# Do anonymous initializes override defaults, or are they run after?

Tags: c#, initialization

If I have a default initializer set, and a define an anonymous one when I create my object. Is the default skipped, or just run before? The reason I want to know is because in the case below, if they are run after, the List object created in the default will be discarded immediately, thus creating unnecessary garbage.

```
class ArrangedPanel : RectElement
{
    public List<RectElement> arrangedChildren = new List<RectElement>();
    public int Padding = 2;
}

//Somewhere else
new ArrangedPanel() 
{ 
   Padding = 5,
   arrangedChildren = new List<RectElement>()
   {
      new ButtonToggle(),
      new ButtonToggle()
   }
}
```

Comment: Note that all the field initializers of the class *and its base classes* run before any constructor body is entered. The order in which things happen is: field initializers are run in textual order for the derived class, then for the base class, until the last base class with an initializer is done. That is, it goes *from derived to base*. Then the constructor bodies are executed, starting with the base constructors and moving back up to the derived constructors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example code the `Padding = 2` occurs before `Padding = 5`.

You are unnecessarily creating a `List<RectElement>`, but I'd challenge you to create a scenario where such unnecessary allocations cause any appreciable performance hit.

Comment: However "unnecessary", it is actually preferable, and advised, considering it is the default initialiser and that elements such as lists _should_ return an empty list instead of `null` (neglecting for a moment that the OP is exposing a bloody variable); and removing the "unnecessary" creation would leave any other API user that doesn't manually create it having to deal with `null` returns for list-types.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I wanted to know. I can change the code so that it's not unnecessarily created. I also realize that this might not change performance much, but it's good to know when designing such systems and Garbage allocation must be kept to a minimum, such as designing for the XBox360.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment: I wouldn't like to expose my varible making it public. I do however want to be able to add objects using collection initializers, thus creating my second problem which is asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647097/possible-to-mix-anonymous-element-initializers-and-anonymous-initializers

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment - There is no semantic difference between initializing the List in the class body or in the constructor, - either way it gets initialized when an instance of the class is constructed. The only difference is the order in which the initializations are performed, there is no visible difference from the POV of an API user.

Comment: @Andrew You're obviously confused... if nothing initialises it, then it doesn't get initialised; if API users _expect_ not to have to deal with `null` lists, then they won't think they _need_ to initialise them, and if it isn't done in the constructor as 'default' then it never gets done, they follow practice and hit `null` and BANG!

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment - Andrew is correct. You might need to re-read his comment.

Comment: @Enigmativity Then enlighten me: _if_ the field is not instantiated by default in the constructor, _and_ is never instantiated by the user of the class (not expecting such requirements for lists), it will magically initialise? This is outright voodoo, and isn't going to happen. No instantiation means no instance.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment - You need to read Andrew's comment again. He said that they get initialized during construction and the only difference between field and constructor initialization is the order that they occur. You're the only one who has said anything about fields not be initialized.

Answer (score 1):

`arrangedChildren` will be set to the last instance you create

for example:

```
arrangedChildren = new List<RectElement>();
arrangedChildren = new List<RectElement>()
   {
      new ButtonToggle(),
      new ButtonToggle()
   }
```

the `arrangedChildren` will point to the second list.
If no other object references to the first one it will disapair (GC).
But if some 1 would keep a reference to the first instance it will stay alive and you could have duplicates or two differents lists where you are working on.

This could cause some problems

Answer (score 1):

From the [C# Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf), section 17.4.5.2

> The instance field variable initializers of a class correspond to a
>   sequence of assignments that are executed  immediately upon entry to
>   any one of the instance constructors (§17.10.2) of that class. The
>   variable  initializers are executed in the textual order in which they
>   appear in the class declaration. The class instance  creation and
>   initialization process is described further in §17.10.

Thus the initializations in the body class declaration will be performed first, followed by the initializations in the constructor. This can be observed directly by viewing the IL output.